# A scroll appears on some entries in reputation leagues

Tags: bug, design

When using Chrome 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10 Pro Fall Creators Update, I get a scroll on some of the [All Time](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow/2008-07-31/2827823?sort=reputationchange#2827823) entries:

[image: All time screenshot]

*Also tested Firefox 57.0 (64-bit), Edge 41.16299.15.0 and IE11, and no scroll appear on those.*

and [Quarterly](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/quarter/stackoverflow):

[image: Quarterly screenshot]

I have now posted the same [at Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303884/a-scroll-appear-on-some-posts).

Comment: no repro in chrome (Version 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-bit)) in Mac...

Comment: I don't think those are posts. They're users, aren't they?

Comment: @jpmc26 Well, the posts contain users, so lets say "yes" :)

Comment: Can't repro on 62.0.3202.94 (Official Build) (64-Bit) with same Windows version as you.

Comment: @chade_ What does your display settings have under "change the size of text, apps and other items" ?

Comment: @LGSon 100% at 1080p/1440p, so the defaults.

Comment: @chade_ As you can see in my self answer, I had 125%, which then appears to be the default for 1920x1080 on 13" screen (which make sense) ... still, no matter the default, if it is set to scale to 125%, this issue occur.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on a dialog with [Shadow Wizard](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303884/a-scroll-appears-on-some-posts-in-real-time-questions-tab-on-stackexchange-com#comment987955_303884) at Stackexchange Meta, it appears this only occurs when the page is zoomed.

As I don't zoom my pages, I overlooked that Windows actually does, where it has a display setting one can change the size of text, apps and other items.

With this set to 125%, which mine were, it create the same effect page zoom does, hence some posts get a scrollbar.

---

Update

The `.league-container` element has its `overflow` set to `auto`, and by that is allowed to render a scrollbar if necessary, which it obviously does in some situations.

If one change it, to e.g. `overflow: hidden`, it goes away.